# Input on decision: file hosting with amazon s3 or similar and php

Tags: php, amazon-s3, hosting, cdn, rackspace-cloud

I appreciate your comments to help me decide on the following.

My requirements:

- I have a site hosted on a shared server and I'm going to provide content to my users. About 60 GB of content (about 2000 files 30mb each. Users will have access to only 20 files at a time), I calculate about 100 GB monthly bandwidth usage.
- Once a user registers for the content, links will be accessible for the user to download. But I want the links to expire in 7 days, with the posibility to increase the expiration time.
- I think that the disk space and bandwidth calls for a service like Amazon S3 or Rackspace Cloud files (or is there an alternative? )
- To manage the expiration I plan to somehow obtain links that expire (I think S3 has that feature, not Rackspace) OR control the expiration date on my database and have a batch process that will rename on a daily basis all 200 files on the cloud and on my database (in case a user copied the direct link, it won't work the next day, only my webpage will have the updated links). PHP is used for programming.

So what do you think? Cloud file hosting is the way to go?  Which one? Does managing the links makes sense that way or it is too difficult to do that through programming (send commands to the cloud server...)

EDIT:
Some host companies have Unlimited space and Bandwidth on their shared plans.. I asked their support staff and they said that they really honor the "unlimited" deal. So 100 GB of transfer a month is ok, the only thing to look out is CPU usage. So going shared hosting is one more alternative to choose from..

FOLLOWUP:
So digging more into this I found that the TOS of the Unlimited plans say that it is not permitted to use the space primarily to host multimedia files. So I decided to go with Amazon s3 and the solution provided by Tom Andersen.

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to rename the files on S3 every day. Just make them private (which is default), and hand out time limited urls for day or a week to anyone who is authorized.

I would consider making the links only good for 20 mins, so that a user has to re-login in order to re-download the files. Then they can't even share the links they get from you.

Comment: Good one. Finally I went with this option.

Answer (score 2):

I personally don't think you necessarily need to go to a cloud based solution for this.  It may be a little costly.  You could simply get a dedicated server instead.  One provider that comes to mind gives 3,000 GB/month of bandwidth on some of their lowest level plans.  That is on a 10Mbit uplink; you can upgrade to 100Mbps for $10/mo of 1Gbit for $20/mo.  I won't mention any names, but you can search for dedicated servers and possibly find one to your liking.

As for expiring the files, just implement that in PHP backed by a database.  You won't have to move files around, store all the files in a directory not accessible from the web, and use a PHP script to determine if the link is valid, and if so read the contents of the file and pass them through to the browser.  If the link is invalid, you can show an error message instead.  It's a pretty simple concept and I think there are a lot of pre-written scripts that do that available, but depending on your needs, it isn't too difficult to do it yourself.

Cloud hosting has advantages, but right now I think its costly and if you aren't trying to spread the load geographically or plan on supporting thousands of simultaneous users and need the elasticity of the cloud, you could possibly use a dedicated server instead.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I thought about dedicated server but the cheapest I've seen starts at $99/mo. Cloud hosting (just for files) for the mentioned space and traffic is about $25 + shared hosting for the site $7 = $32. And I don't go through the hassle of setting up and maintaining a dedicated server.

Comment: If you go the cloud route, with S3, you also learn about that - which is a great knowledge set. Those are big files. If someone copies the link into a web browser bookmark, then hits the link every time they want the file, is that OK? if not you may be want to use shorter expiring urls, and force people to log in again to get to download twice, etc.

Comment: The files are not that big really... ahh I think you thought 200 files, 60 GB each... it's 60 GB in total :)  I have another alternative, editing the question now.

Comment: oh my mistake it is 2000 files, about 30 mb each.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for S3 but I use Rackspace Cloud files and servers.

It's good in that you don't pay for incoming bandwidth, so uploads are super cheap.

I would do it like this:

1. Upload all the files you need to a 'private' container
2. Create a public container with CDN enabled
3. That'll give you a special url like http://c3214146.r65.ce3.rackcdn.com
4. Make your own CNAME DNS record for your domain point to that, like: http://cdn.yourdomain.com
5. When a user requests a file, use the [COPY api operation](http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Copy_Object-d1e2241.html) with a [long random filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406513/how-to-serve-files-stored-in-cloud/8415151#8415151) to do a server side copy from the private container to the public container.
6. Store the filename in a mysql DB for your app
7. Once the file expires, use the [DELETE api operation](http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Delete_Object-d1e2264.html), then the [PURGE api operation](http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Purge_CDN-Enabled_Objects-d1e3858.html) to get it out of the CDN .. finally delete the record from the mysql table.

With the PURGE command .. I heard it doesn't work 100% of the time and it may leave the file around for an extra day .. also in the docs it says to reserve it's use for only emergency things.

Edit: I just heard, there's a 25 purge per day limit.

However personally I've just used delete on objects and found that took it out the CDN straight away. In summary, the worst case would be that the file would still be accessible on some CDN nodes for 24 hours after deletion.

Edit: You can change the TTL (caching time) on the CDN nodes .. default is 72 hours so might pay to set it to something lower .. but not so low that you loose the advantage of CDN.

The advantages I find with the CDN are:

1. It pushes content right out to end users far away from the USA servers and gives super fast download times for them
2. If you have a super popular file .. it won't take out your site when 1000 people start trying to download it .. as they'd all get copies pushed out the whatever CDN node they were closest to.

Comment: Good alternative to the renaming idea, great info